# R issue with adding a new column while working on Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am working on Confusion matrix in R.

I have the following data

```
row.names    A    B    C    Actual
d1           1    1    1    1
d2           0    0    1    0
d3           1    1    0    0
d4           0    0    0    0
d5           0    1    1    1
d6           1    0    1    1
```

I need to create a new column `Classifier` which has value 1 if `rowsums(data[,1:3])` greater than or equal to 2, and 0 if the rowsum is less than 2.

Can anyone provide me a hint how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
data$Classifier <- (rowSums(data[,1:3]) >=2)+0L
data
#   A B C Actual Classifier
#d1 1 1 1      1          1
#d2 0 0 1      0          0
#d3 1 1 0      0          1
#d4 0 0 0      0          0
#d5 0 1 1      1          1
#d6 1 0 1      1          1
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), B = c(1L, 0L, 
1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L), C = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Actual = c(1L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C", "Actual"), 
row.names = c("d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6"),
class = "data.frame")
```